# Images Not Aligned - What's Wrong?

Tags: image, alignment, css-float

I couldn't figure out what's causing the misalignment of the images on the 3rd row in this [page](http://www.criminal-lawyers.com.au/criminal-law/case-studies). Here are the codes (just for the 3rd row though):

```
<div class="one-fourth" style="float:left;">
<center><a href="/criminal-law/case-studies/fraud-dishonesty-theft-offences"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/fraud-theft-case-studies-150x150.jpg" alt="fraud &amp; theft case studies" width="150" height="150" /></a>
<h5><a title="Fraud Dishonesty Theft Case Studies" href="/criminal-law/case-studies/fraud-dishonesty-theft-offences">Fraud, Theft & Dishonesty</h5></center>
</div>

<div class="one-fourth" style="float:left;">
<center><a href="/criminal-law/case-studies/murder-manslaughter-offences"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/murder-manslaughter-case-studies-150x150.jpg" alt="murder &amp; manslaughter case studies" width="150" height="150" /></a>
<h5><a title="Murder &amp; Manslaughter Case Studies" href="/criminal-law/case-studies/murder-manslaughter-offences">Murder
Manslaughter</a></h5></center>
</div>

<div class="one-fourth" style="float:left;">
<center><a href="/criminal-law/case-studies/perjury-offences"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/perjury-case-studies-150x150.jpg" alt="perjury case studies" width="150" height="150" /></a>
<h5><a title="Perjury Case Studies" href="/criminal-law/case-studies/perjury-offences">Perjury
Offences</a></h5></center>
</div>
```

I've run through the codes for the nth time but I don't see anything amiss.

Can anybody shed light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close an `<a>` tag.

In the third line of the first item you have:

```
Fraud, Theft & Dishonesty</h5>
```

It should be:

```
Fraud, Theft & Dishonesty</a></h5>
```

Comment: You're right!!! That definitely did the trick. I so want to punish my eyes at the moment (to think I've run through the codes over and over again!) . Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok you have Something there:

```
<a title="Fraud Dishonesty Theft Case Studies" href="/criminal-law/case-studies/fraud-dishonesty-theft-offences">
```

That element has a margin-bottom of 5px. If you remove those 5 pixels, you might get the thing aligned!

Comment: All of them actually had that same margin-bottom so it shouldn't make that section misalign. Anyways, finally figured what was wrong. Thanks still.